# Implement Django oauth to 2 Different User Models

Tags: python, django, django-models, oauth-2.0

Is there any way to have Django oauth for 2 Different types of User Models?

I am working on a site which has Customer and Business, and both will have their seperate logins. There is no such information  that they will have in common and really can't use common db table for both.

We will be having different database tables for customers and business, thus need different oauth tables. I couldn't find any way to accomplish it.

Comment: I'd suggest you separate the login info and model from the role based model i.e user has a role object then role is a generic base class for Business and Customer. Take a look at the inheritance structure, you don't want to duplicate auth logic

Comment: @pypypy makes sense, thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

try django-role-permission

https://django-role-permissions.readthedocs.io/en/stable/

This has role based permission. If you go through the example, probably you will find exactly you are looking for..good luck